# Arguments for/against using a third party "Rapid development environment"?

Tags: language-agnostic, development-environment

I just started working for a company that uses a "Rapid Development Environment" (RDE) supplied by a third party.  The idea is that you can specify things like: "display data in grid", "datasource", "sort by" and it generates an a ASP.NET application that does all of those things.

I'm personally not a huge fan for the following reasons:

- You are at the mercy of the RDE with
  regards to what level of control you
  have.  For example there is no
  try/catch/fail mechanism.
- If there is a bug in the RDE there is
  nothing you can do, you have to wait
  for them to release a fix.
- I'm not sure that it speeds things up
  all that much.
- There is no way you are going to find
  someone with X years of experience
  using some backwoods RDE.  Every new
  employee is starting from scratch
- You can't integrate many common tools with it.  Source control would be an example of this.  While i'm sure I could take the EXTREAMLY verbose xml files used to generate the application and manually insert them into Source control there is no way for me to just right click and checkin.  Even if I do that there would be nothing meaningful displayed if you do a diff...

Has anyone found these things useful?  They seem like a gimic to keep costs down to me...

Comment: Cant say I'm a big fan of magic stuff like that? But if its open source and semi transparent then maybe...

Comment: Aah, nostalgia :) I had the "pleasure" of working with a similar tool once and encountered all 5 of your points. Also, no API docs, and the original publisher had abandoned the product which meant no bug fixes, ever...

Comment: @SimonJ, what product was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use any tool/framework/environment/etc that I cannot bypass whenever I want to.
I don't care how good the product looks on paper or what impressing demos I'm shown.

If the product isn't mature and expressive enough to offer the possibility to work around it or hack/plug into it, I'll pass.